# Joomla! 2.5 template design book

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm looking for a complete book for Joomla! 2.5 template design.
(I want to learn the best, the newest and the most standard way to code Joomla 2.5 template)

What do you suggest? (cost is not a problem!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start off with the free stuff. The Joomla wiki page [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template) on creating a basic template. Personally I found [this](http://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/1131-creating-a-joomla-template-from-scratch.html) video made at a Joomla Conference pretty helpful. [This](http://www.compassdesigns.net/joomla-tutorials/joomla-15-template-tutorial) tutorial whist for Joomla 1.5 very little template wise changed from 1.5 to 1.6-2.5 versions.

Also make sure you're happy with non-joomla css/html/php templates as that is what these are at the end of the day with some extra bits here and there.

Once you've done that have a look at some of the existing frameworks. Most are available for free. The yootheme warp master theme [here](http://www.yootheme.com/themes/warp-framework), the [Nooku](http://www.nooku.org/) framework, [Gantry](http://www.gantry-framework.org/) Framework whilst all customizable if you want to make your own template on a existing framework for the first couple of go's to get a feel for it. You can also learn a lot about how site development works from the way that other people have built their templates if you wish to work that way!

So far 0 pence spent and a pretty good idea of how Joomla templates work!! If you are desperate to spend dosh go for the offical Joomla Book on it [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Joomla-Templates-Angie-Radtke/dp/0321827317/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1350256307&sr=8-1).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is here:
[http://www.amazon.com/Joomla-Templates-Press-Angie-Radtke/dp/0321827317/ref=pd_sim_b_7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321827317)

Publication Date: August 1, 2012